# Is there a function $f(x)$ for which $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ converges but $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i)$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was recently learning about improper integrals, so I am not that advanced, and I asked myself whether there is some function $f(x)$ for which $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ with the limits being $a$ or $b$, it doesn't matter, converges while $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i)$ diverges.
I have found similar questions being asked like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2933007/example-of-a-function-for-which-int-1-infty-fx-dx-diverges-and-sum-1) one but there are usually the other way around, so the integral is divergent and the sum convergent, like with $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$.

Comment: Let $f(x) = 0$ for non-integer $x$ and let $f(n) = 1/n$ for positive integers $n$.  If you want something continuous, You can add little line segments in the graph from $0$ to these integer points so the graph of $f$ is a series of spiky triangles. The integral will converge as long as the triangles get narrow enough (you can arrange for the $n$th base to be $1/2^n$, for example) but this won't change how high they go or the divergence of the sum.

Comment: Was the integral supposed to be over a bounded domain? It seems you meant $\int_a^\infty f(x) dx$.

Comment: Yes or some other improper integral like $\int_0^6 \frac{1} {x}dx$

Comment: It isn't clear to me why one owuld expect any relation between the infinite sum and the integral of $f$ over a bounded interval. I assumed $\int_a^{\infty}$ in my example above.

Comment: $\sin(x^2)$ is a continuous example.

Comment: I mean... $f(x)=1$ with $a=0$ and $b=1$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2532382/42969

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show whether the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n(2+(-1)^n)} $ converges or diverges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402900/how-can-i-show-whether-the-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-1nn2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, it is easy because the integral is over a finite interval.  $f(x)=1$ suffices.  It is a little harder if you make the integral $\int_1^\infty$ but not much.  We know that the sum of $\frac 1i$ diverges but we can make the integral converge by making a bump at each natural and making the bumps get narrower and narrower.
$$f(x)=\begin {cases} \frac 1k & x\in [k-\frac 1k,k+\frac 1k],k \in \Bbb N \\0&\text{otherwise} \end {cases}$$
will work.  The area of each rectangle is $\frac 1{k^2}$ and we know the sum of that converges.  As leslie townes pointed out, you could also just make $f(x)=\frac 1k$ at the naturals and $0$ elsewhere, which makes the integral identically $0$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what $a$ and $b$ are supposed to be, but I'll assume $a=1$ and $b=\infty$.  A simple example is $$f(x)=\cases{1,&$x\in \mathbb{N}$\\0,&$x\notin \mathbb{N}$}$$

You can modify this example to make $f$ continuous, by making it piecewise linear, or even $C^\infty$ by using bump functions.